# Is there a plugin to have DMCA takedown notice form in Wordpress?

Tags: plugins, copyright

I was looking to do something like this in Wordpress:

https://www.mysavings.com/removal-request.asp

But I can't find any plugin that makes that.

I hope you can help me with ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to make your own form. One of the most popular contact form plugins is Contact Form 7. You can create a form with any number of fields/content/text, etc. A bit easier than creating your own form (which you could do with a template).

See https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/ .

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. There are things you can do to the form to reduce potential for spam-bots; I made a small plugin that uses some effective techniques; in case you are interested: https://wordpress.org/plugins/formspammertrap-for-contact-form-7/ .